# What is this hinged metal hardware with an eyelet?

Tags: hanging

Does anyone know what this is? I think its something related to picture hanging, but not sure.

Its about 4-5cm long

[image: what is this?]
[image: what is this?]

Comment: I believe it's a picture frame hanger but I'm not able to find a reference for this exact style.

Comment: The other black object appears to be a telephone handset cord.

Comment: @MichaelKaras  there is also appears to be a table top too, thats 2 items identified

Comment: You two should team up. Your observation skills are unmatched.

Comment: I think there’s a stack of papers in the first image. Look at that, 3/4 things in identified!

Comment: @Tim  yes you right, this is a fun game!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a "fangs" style fastener- I use similar styles to hang junk in my cubicle. The teeth latch on to the foam board in my cubicle walls, or it could also be used to grab the foam backing of a picture frame. Found it on amazon by googling "Eye Fastener for Foam Board"

[Drytac Push/Pull Hinged Hanger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BNBE1S2)

[image: Drytac Push/Pull Hinged Hanger]

Comment: Nice find on that one!

Comment: yeah, great job, really didn't think I would get an answer ,  I have had an unmarked pack sitting on my desk for over a year

Comment: Works decently on drywalls also, but dont suspend anything fragile or expensive...

Answer (score 2):

The hinged nature of the part makes me think that it may be part of a box latch of some type. The part shown may be designed to snap onto a plastic or metal part box lid.

The working nature of the latch would be similar to this:

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.globalsources.com/si/AS/Shenzhen-Hongshengfeng/6008827742886/pdtl/Wooden-Box-Locks-Small-Jewelry-Box-Latches-Antiqu/1122673370.htm)*</sup>

Comment: I don't think this correct, but a good guess.  I think the teeth are ment to  be hammered into mdf or something. But I'm really looking its proper name

Comment: I don't get the DV.  If you disagree, comment on it but not a reason for DV.+